# Casting from Object to ArrayList

Tags: java, jsp

```
A a = new A();

ArrayList<A> myA = (ArrayList<A>)request.getAttribute("message");
```

Error message:

> Type safety: Unchecked cast from `Object` to `ArrayList<A>`

Attribute "message" is sent in `ArrayList<A>` from another jsp page.

Comment: That's not an error, it's a warning. You can [suppress it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html) if you're sure it's correct. You can also use `instanceof` to check the type of the object first.

Comment: @1blustone: Not in terms of generics - you can check whether it's an `ArrayList`, but you can't use `instanceof` to check that it's an `ArrayList<A>`, as there's no such thing at execution time.

Comment: @JonSkeet true, wasn't aware it was a generic list due to the original post. Didn't realize that casting to a raw list wouldn't result in this warning. I suppose you could cast to an `ArrayList<?>` or simply the raw type instead if the intended return type is known.

Comment: I didn't get the question. Could you please explain more on what your expecting here? This is just a warning, so you should still be able to proceed. Are you getting a `java.lang.ClassCastException` when running this?

Comment: @1blustone: Without the generics aspect, the warning wouldn't have been there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do away with that warning, I would do something like below:

```
   List<A> castToArrayList() {

        Object obj = request.getAttribute("message");

        return ((List<?>) obj).stream().map(el -> (A) el).collect(Collectors.toList());
    
or  

    return ((List<?>)obj)
                     .stream()
                     .filter(A.class::isInstance)
                     .map(A.class::cast)
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just put an annotation if it's bothering you.

```
@SuppressWarning ("unchecked")
List<A> myA = (ArrayList< A >)request.getAttribute("message");
```

Casting an object to some generic type is not safe, it could cause `ClassCastException`. You can put it in try and handle your response in case of invalid input.

There is no way to determine whether the `List` really should have the generic parameters `<A>`. You must know beforehand what the parameters should be (or you'll find out when you get a `ClassCastException`). This is why the code generates a warning, because the compiler can't possibly know whether is safe.

Comment: You've misunderstood the point of the warning. It's not a matter of "casting an object to some type" - that doesn't produce a warning in itself: `Object x = "foo"; String y = (String) x;`. The point is that casting something that was created in source code as an `ArrayList<Integer>` to an `ArrayList<String>` *won't* cause an exception - that cast will succeed as the type information isn't present at execution time. It's the implicit cast when accessing an element that will cause the exception.

Comment: @JonSkeet There is no way to determine whether the List really should have the generic parameters <A>. You must know beforehand what the parameters should be (or you'll find out when you get a ClassCastException). This is why the code generates a warning, because the compiler can't possibly know whether is safe.

Comment: Well yes - but that's not really a matter of the *compiler* knowing whether it's safe or not... a compiler almost never knows that a cast is safe. And the exception wouldn't be thrown by this line of code if the type argument is wrong. I still think this answer is misleading - it's conflating the *regular* casting aspects with the ones that are specific to generics.